# Looking for Scientific Computing Qualifying exams, appropriate to ask on SE?

Tags: support

I have a Qualifying Exam in Scientific Computing fast approaching. My school doesn't make many past exams available for practice, but I presume some schools do. I was hoping that perhaps people on SE might have suggestions of university websites that have old exams (if they have solutions too, that would be the best!).

But I'm unsure if this is an appropriate question to post on SE. Moreover, I am unsure if asking if this is an appropriate question is an appropriate question for meta. But I figured I'd have to start somewhere. Am I allowed to ask this? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Perhaps http://scicomp.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Generally, "is X appropriate for Y?" is appropriate for meta.Y